# Cordova Google Map crashes while plotting polylines

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 2.2.3 for building hybrid mobile app. I am using [Cordova Google Map plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) for plotting some points on google map. Same code base is working for all android devices fine but when I try to plot polyline in iOS(any device), the app gets crashed.

I am getting the points in below format -

```
{"lat":22.51,"lng":88.26},{"lat":22.549092,"lng":88.284892}
```

and then add the points to map -

```
map.addPolyline({
                    'points': points,
                    'color': "#DAA520",
                    'width': 6,
                    'name': '<line Name>'
                }, function (polyline) {
                        polyline.on(plugin.google.maps.event.POLYLINE_CLICK, function (latlng) {
                        map.addMarker({
                            position: latlng,
                        }, function (marker) {
                           //some code to show the line details when clicked
                        });

                    });
                });
```

When I run the same code in emulator, there are no issues and app runs fine. I guess there is some memory issue and I am struggling with same.

Comment: I guess your points are too much. Otherwise, `points` does not contain any points.

Comment: I have proper checking of points not having any points. I also think I have too many points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. After checking some points I found out that it is breaking after few 100 points. So I am querying now some 100 points and rest based on user's query.